# QGIS Web Client zoom and scale

Tags: qgis, scale, qgis-web-client, zoom

I have a problem with setting up zoom levels and max/min scale in QGIS web client. It looks like that values used in GlobalOptions.js file does not apply. Right now ZOOM_LEVELS is 70, maxScale 50 and minScale 40000.

Comment: Ok, it looks like zoom and min/max scale didn't work because of background layers. I can set ZOOM_LEVELS with background layers in WebGisInit.js, but still didn't find place to set min/max scale.

Comment: have you find out a way to increase the zoom levels?